# Speechrecognizer not working for quiz app where After each correct/incorrect it moves to next one

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to build an app for quiz using a Speech recognizer it only works for 1 question what if I have a series of questions After each correct/incorrect it moves to the next one, which I already used for the loop here is not working code is not going inside the speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() this
if code goes inside it my problem will be solved If anyone knows other methods please answer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText tv;
ImageButton btn;
TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
int count = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);


    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
    }

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            }
        }
    });

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] arr = {"2 multiply 2 is", "4 multiply 4 is ", "3 into 3 is", };
            int i=0;
            while (i<arr.length ) {
                textToSpeech.speak(arr[i], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                        speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int finalI = i;
                speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int error) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                        ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(speechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                        String res = data.get(0);
                        tv.setText(res);
                        if (arr[finalI].equals("2 multiply 2 is")){
                            if (res.equals("4")) {
                                textToSpeech.speak("correct", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                                speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                                data.remove(0);

                            } else {
                                textToSpeech.speak("Incorrect", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                                speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                                data.remove(0);

                            }
                        }
                        if (arr[finalI].equals("4 multiply 4 is")){
                            if (res.equals("8")) {
                                textToSpeech.speak("correct", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                                speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                                data.remove(0);

                            } else {
                                textToSpeech.speak("Incorrect", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                                speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                                data.remove(0);

                            }
                        }




                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                    }
                });

           i++; }


        }
    });




}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```